# transforming JSON data returned from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery and AJAX to get a bunch of results back from my api.

this gets all the exams

```
    $.fn.examEvents = (function () {
        return $.ajax("/api/scores/exams", {
            type: "GET",
            data: JSON.stringify(this),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data, status, XHR) {
                getScores(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

this is my callback function
This gets a bunch of objects that look like this in my console:

```
[
Object { id="1", examTitle="exam I", startTime="1-1-2014T09:20:00",   endTime="1-1-2014T011:20:00"}
Object { id="2", examTitle="exam II", startTime="1-2-2014T09:20:00", endTime="1-2-2014T011:20:00"}
Object { id="3", examTitle="exam III", startTime="1-3-2014T09:20:00", endTime="1-3-2014T011:20:00"}
]


    function getScores(response) {
        console.log(response);   
        //this writes out everything as a bunch
        //of response objects to the console that 
        //contain properties(id, examTitle, startTime, endTime)

        //transform them
        var evt = {
            title: response.examTitle,
            start: response.startTime,
            end: response.endTime
        };
        console.log(evt.title);    
        //this is undefined, even though the response
        //objects contains a property called 'title' so I 
        //was expecting my console to be filled with a 
        //bunch of event titles.
    };
```

So it 'works', meaning it's getting the data.

But I want to wrap and transform that data 
into another object called 'evt' but that is always coming back undefined.

So I want to be able to do this:

```
console.log(evt.title);
console.log(evt.start);
console.log(evt.end);
```

etc...

So my question is, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an array of object returned by the ajax call, you have to iterate it to get the items:

```
function getScores(response) {

 $.each(response, function (index, item) {

    var evt = {
        title: item.examTitle,
        start: item.startTime,
        end: item.endTime
    };

    console.log(evt.title);

 })
}
```

or you can access items using index, i am writing for getting first item of array:

```
function getScores(response) {

var evt = {
            title: response[0].examTitle,
            start: response[0].startTime,
            end: response[0].endTime
        };

        console.log(evt.title);
}
```